# Changing the BorderBrush of a button during MouseOver

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml

To start, it's important to note that I'm doing this in Silverlight, so Style Triggers aren't available.

I'm trying to create a custom Button template. I've avoided doing this in the past, so this is my first attempt at something like this. I want a button that is essentially transparent. When I mouseover, the button border should appear. When I click, I want the background to darken a bit. The trouble I'm having right now is getting the BorderBrush to change on mouseover.

Note, in my test code here I'm starting with the borderbrush as visible and trying to make it invisible on the mouseover, which is the opposite of what I'm trying to accomplish in the end.

```
<DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="BorderBrush" />
```

Was my best attempt, but I just get an error saying 'Cannot resolve TargetName BorderBrush.'

Also, how would I start with my LinearGradient for my borderbrush defined like it is, but just with the opacity set to 0 (so that I can set it to 1 when I want it to appear).

Below is my entire template:

```
<Style x:Key="ButtonStyle_menu" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#000000"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="3"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" >
            <Setter.Value>
                <!--Value="#FF000000"-->
                <LinearGradientBrush>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFA3AEB9" Offset="0" />
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF8399A9" Offset="0.375" />
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF718597" Offset="0.375" />
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF3C4400" Offset="1" />
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Setter.Value>

        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Grid>
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <!--<DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="BorderBrush" />-->
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(frameworkelement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="BorderBrush" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="0.4" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="DisabledVisualElement"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualElement"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused"/>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Border x:Name="Background" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                            <Border.Background>
                                <SolidColorBrush Opacity="0" />
                                <!--
                                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                    <GradientStop Color="#FF707070" Offset="0"/>
                                    <GradientStop Color="#FF666666" Offset="0.49"/>
                                    <GradientStop Color="#FF5e5e5e" Offset="0.51"/>
                                    <GradientStop Color="#FF535353" Offset="1"/>
                                </LinearGradientBrush>-->
                            </Border.Background>
                        </Border>
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}">
                            <ContentPresenter.Effect>
                                <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="3" ShadowDepth="2" Opacity="0.5"/>
                            </ContentPresenter.Effect>
                        </ContentPresenter>
                        <Rectangle x:Name="DisabledVisualElement" Fill="#FFFFFFFF" IsHitTestVisible="false" Opacity="0"/>
                        <Rectangle x:Name="FocusVisualElement" IsHitTestVisible="false" Margin="1" Opacity="0" Stroke="#FF6DBDD1" StrokeThickness="1"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have something similar, a white border appears on mouseover, the pressed visual state can be easily modified to show a darker background on button click.

```
 <Style TargetType="Button" x:Name="ButtonStyle4">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Canvas Height="15" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,0,21,0">
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="#FFFFF6F6" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Stroke).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="rectangle" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled"/>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Rectangle x:Name="rectangle" Stroke="{StaticResource MenuBarBackground}" Width="84" Height="25">
                            <Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                                <RadialGradientBrush>
                                    <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0"/>
                                    <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="1"/>
                                </RadialGradientBrush>
                            </Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                        </Rectangle>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="UnderlineTextBlock" Text="Manage Apps" Margin="2,0,21,0" TextDecorations="Underline"/>
                        <!--<ContentPresenter Name="btnManageApps" Height="25" Width="170" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,1.367" Content="Manage Apps"/>-->
                    </Canvas>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource MenuBarButtonTextColour}"/>
    </Style>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I tried it, but I just get the error 'TargetProperty (Shape.Stroke).(SolidColorBrush.Color) cannot be resolved'

Comment: That could be because in my example the rectangle is pointing to the property "MenuBarBackground" which i have defined as a solid color brush in a resources file. <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MenuBarBackground" Color="#FF404040" />

Answer (score 0):

I have something similar.
The problem you were having with "Cannot resolve TargetName BorderBrush" is because you don't have an element *named* BorderBrush. The TargetName should refer to the name of an element, not a property name.

This is example is pretty basic and just changes one property of one element ...

```
 <Style x:Key="ButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Grid Height="24" MinHeight="24" MaxHeight="24">
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                    <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.1"/>
                                </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="rectangle" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="rectangle" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Rectangle x:Name="rectangle" Margin="0" StrokeThickness="0" RadiusX="5" RadiusY="5" Height="24" MinHeight="24" MaxHeight="24" Opacity="0">
                            <Rectangle.Fill>
                                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                    <GradientStop Color="#FF00A4CB" Offset="0"/>
                                    <GradientStop Color="#FF006BA2" Offset="0.991"/>
                                </LinearGradientBrush>
                            </Rectangle.Fill>
                        </Rectangle>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock" Margin="10,5,10,6" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

This changes the opacity property, of the element named 'rectangle' to 1 when the button receives a `mouseover` or `pressed` event.

Within the ControlTemplate just add whatever elements you want (give them a name) and then hook up the events to change the properties on those elements. .

Answer (score 0):

If you want to animate the border thickness of the Background element, try this:

```
<ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Background" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.BorderThickness)">
    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00">
        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
            <Thickness>0</Thickness>
        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
</ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
```